# In an experiment w/binomial responses, some subjects gave the same answer for all trials. [How] can a Mixed Effects model (R's lmer) deal with this?

Tags: r, logistic, experiment-design, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I recently ran a pilot of an experiment on Amazon's Mechanical Turk. In the experiment, participants read 5 items, and answered a yes/no question about each one. A between-participants factor was manipulated, which I'll call "Intention."

After completing the pilot of the experiment, I attempted to analyze the results in R using the 'lme4' package.

```
lmer_max    = glmer(formula= Resp ~ 1+Intention + (1|PartCode)+ (1|Item), data=df, family="binomial")
lmer_nomain = glmer(formula= Resp ~ 1           + (1|PartCode)+ (1|Item), data=df, family="binomial")
```

Unfortunately, lme4 seems to dislike the data: using an older version of the package, the model fails to converge, and using a more recent version of the package, the model fit is worse than expected.

Looking at the results, it's apparent that many subject's responded "yes" across all 5 vignettes. There's nothing wrong with them doing this within the context of the experiment, but I suspect it's one major source of problems in analyzing the data. One piece of confirmation for this possibility is plotting the lmer model using the `effects` package (Resp=0: No ; Resp=1: Yes):

[image: a ceiling effect]

This ceiling effect is unique to how the model is dealing with the random effects: the actual split between Yes's and No's is about Yes=2/3, No=1/3.

My question is basically: how should I deal with this? I have three main options in mind, but am open to others.

1. **Re-design experiment so that there's more variation within each subject.** Obviously this is ideal, but it's also the riskiest and most difficult to do: the yes/no question participants are being asked is sort of philosophical in nature, and people come in with strong pre-conceptions. The manipulation in question seems to push their responses around, but there's still a lot of across-subject variability, and ultimately it may be difficult to guarantee that no subjects gives the same response on all trials.
2. **Re-design experiment so that there's FORCED variation within each subject.** Currently, subjects are asked this yes/no question for five items, and yes or no is a perfectly valid response for each. However, I could add a "catch" item in which "no" is the only plausible response, then remove any subjects who answered "yes" on all 6 items. This would guarantee that subjects, at maximum, answered 'yes' only 5 out of 6 times. However, this feels like a slightly odd strategy: instead of having some participants who gave the same response across all items, there will now be an item that has the same response across all participants. Is this a problem? I suppose the difference would be that, right now, about half of subjects had the same response on every item, whereas under this strategy, only 1/6 items would have the same response for every participant.
3. **Re-do analysis so that there's forced variation within each subject.** This is the laziest possibility, but I thought I'd ask. Is it in any way kosher to introduce a dummy item/trial into the data frame, in which all participants responded "no," simply to remove the difficulties that lmer is having? That is, instead of doing possibility 2, I would simulate possibility 2 with the current data. Or perhaps there's a way of telling lmer not to freak out over subjects who gave the same response across items?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried simulating some data to see how it behaves?